# What you use to get your poker "A" when playing live?

Tags: etiquette

I mean, headphones, kind of music you listen, playing other games on celular (if allowed) to "distract" a bit, taking a walk, cigars, drinks, gums in mouth, playing with chips... what is your stuff around you to keep you in good poker transe?
And obvius, the advantages and downs of each thing on play.

Comment: I guess a talk about shades could be usefull here too.

Answer (score 1):

never play poker when you are tired or drunk. never! :) taking a walk is good option, it clears your mind) other things like headphones, cigars and chip tricks are only distract me. but it's very personal.

Comment: I miss the things you use to keep good playing..so you use nothing? do use shades in live play? tks for answering.

Comment: i look stupid in shades:) i use nothing, except of clear mind and good mood

Answer (score 1):

I focus on my opponents. I watch for tells, determine styles of play, see if I can find things to exploit at the table. That keeps me busy enough.

Okay, I admit it, I also play with my chips.